# Offset in creating delay between two PWM in STM32 board

Tags: stm32

I generate two PWM outputs from [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf) Nucleo board (STM32F302R8). I use TIM1 and and TIM2 for PWM outputs and TIM6 to create delay between the PWM outputs. I want to create 100 us delay but my code generates 110 us delay. And seems always 10 us off.

Here is my entire project for STM32CubeMX: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15TK3thfZ4IuCq0NvC9nqF8EFTHBPXHpw/view?usp=sharing

**What could be the reason for this offset and is there  way to minimize it?**

In main I use the following:

```
void StartGeneration (void)
{
    firstTimer = 0;
    TIM6->ARR = 100;
    TIM6->CNT = 0;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim6);
}
```

And in interrupt:

```
void TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_DAC_IRQn 0 */
      if(firstTimer)
      {
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim6);
      }
      else
      {
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
        firstTimer = 1;
      }
  /* USER CODE END TIM6_DAC_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim6);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_DAC_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_DAC_IRQn 1 */
}
```

**Here is my main.c**

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim6;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
uint8_t firstTimer = 0;
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

void StartGeneration (void)
{
    firstTimer = 0;
    TIM6->ARR = 100;
    TIM6->CNT = 0;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim6);
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  StartGeneration();
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_TIM1;
  PeriphClkInit.Tim1ClockSelection = RCC_TIM1CLK_HCLK;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 72-1;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 720-1;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 360;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2State = TIM_BREAK2_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Polarity = TIM_BREAK2POLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Filter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 72-1;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 720-1;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 360;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM6 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 1 */
  htim6.Instance = TIM6;
  htim6.Init.Prescaler = 72-1;
  htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim6.Init.Period = 720-1;
  htim6.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim6, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 38400;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

**And the interrupt file stm32f3xx_it.c**

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    stm32f3xx_it.c
  * @brief   Interrupt Service Routines.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f3xx_it.h"
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN TD */
extern uint8_t firstTimer;
/* USER CODE END TD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/* External variables --------------------------------------------------------*/
extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim6;
/* USER CODE BEGIN EV */

/* USER CODE END EV */

/******************************************************************************/
/*           Cortex-M4 Processor Interruption and Exception Handlers          */
/******************************************************************************/
/**
  * @brief This function handles Non maskable interrupt.
  */
void NMI_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN NonMaskableInt_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END NonMaskableInt_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN NonMaskableInt_IRQn 1 */
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END NonMaskableInt_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Hard fault interrupt.
  */
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Memory management fault.
  */
void MemManage_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Pre-fetch fault, memory access fault.
  */
void BusFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN BusFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END BusFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_BusFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_BusFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Undefined instruction or illegal state.
  */
void UsageFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN UsageFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles System service call via SWI instruction.
  */
void SVC_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVCall_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SVCall_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVCall_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SVCall_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Debug monitor.
  */
void DebugMon_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DebugMonitor_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DebugMonitor_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DebugMonitor_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DebugMonitor_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Pendable request for system service.
  */
void PendSV_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles System tick timer.
  */
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_IncTick();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 1 */
}

/******************************************************************************/
/* STM32F3xx Peripheral Interrupt Handlers                                    */
/* Add here the Interrupt Handlers for the used peripherals.                  */
/* For the available peripheral interrupt handler names,                      */
/* please refer to the startup file (startup_stm32f3xx.s).                    */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
  * @brief This function handles TIM1 break and TIM15 interrupts.
  */
void TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles TIM1 update and TIM16 interrupts.
  */
void TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles TIM1 trigger, commutation and TIM17 interrupts.
  */
void TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles TIM1 capture compare interrupt.
  */
void TIM1_CC_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_CC_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_CC_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_CC_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_CC_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles TIM2 global interrupt.
  */
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim2);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles TIM6 global interrupt, DAC interrupts.
  */
void TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_DAC_IRQn 0 */
      if(firstTimer)
      {
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim6);
      }
      else
      {
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
        firstTimer = 1;
      }
  /* USER CODE END TIM6_DAC_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim6);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_DAC_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_DAC_IRQn 1 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */
```

Comment: It's possible that the different execution paths in the `if`/`else` in your TIM6 IRQ handler accounts for the 10us difference.

Comment: Not a good solution, but what if you set it to 90 us?

Comment: @winny I do that already as the only solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by a difference between the two timers being used.

Timer 1 has break inputs. Timer 2 has not. And because of that I think the call to `HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT()` will take a different amount of time.

This is the reason for my thinking:

```
...
  if(IS_TIM_BREAK_INSTANCE(htim->Instance) != RESET)
  {
    /* Enable the main output */
    __HAL_TIM_MOE_ENABLE(htim);
  }
...
```

An additional bit has to be set in case of TIM1 compared to TIM2.

To reduce the error, what I would do is configure everything in TIM1 and TIM2 and just set the enable bit in the interrupt. Not sure if there is a way with the HAL, maybe the Low Level HAL is better suited for a task like this.

Comment: I will try to use TIM15 instead of TIM1 then and let you know.

Comment: @ty_1917 TIM15 also has a break input, the result will not change.

Comment: Indeed didnt work. But I also disabled TIM2 and then tried TIM1 and TIM15 (both have break inputs) I still have this offset. Do you have Nucelo as well?

Comment: @ty_1917 I have a different one, the timers don't change much though. Currently I don't have the measurement equipment at hand to measure these differences though.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hardware solution, but you need to use TIM3 or TIM4 instead of TIM6.

Timers can be configured to trigger each other on specific events. Here, both TIM1 & TIM2 are configured in **[Slave Mode = Trigger]**. TIM1 & TIM2 are not enabled by default. They are automatically enabled as soon as they receive **ITR** (internal trigger) signal from their master, TIM3.

We need to configure TIM3 to generate two different kinds of trigger outputs. First, it's configured in **[Master Mode = Enable]**, so that as soon as TIM3 is enabled, so is TIM1. This means that TIM1 & TIM3 start counting at the exact same time. We also configure TIM3 so that it generates an update event after 100 us.

After starting TIM3 (and slave TIM1), TIM3 master mode is re-configured to **[Master Mode = Update]**. In this configuration, TIM3 generates a trigger output after 100 us, and this time, it starts TIM2.

I have tested it on a BluePill board (STM32F103C8). You can't use TIM6 as the master timer, because TIM1 & TIM2 has no ITR connections to it. BTW, TIM3 (master timer) is still running and it's up to you to decide how to use it. You can now disable it or use it for some other purpose.

I don't use Cube or HAL libraries, so I can only provide bare-metal register code. In the following code, it's assumed that TIM & GPIO clocks are already enabled and GPIO pins are already configured. I let STM32F103 to run at default 8 MHz HSI clock.

```
// TIM1 Settings
TIM1->ARR = 8000 - 1; // 1 kHz PWM @ 8 MHz TIM clock frequency
TIM1->CCR1 = 4000 - 1; // 50% duty cycle
TIM1->CCMR1 |= (0b110u << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos); // PWM Mode 1
TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E; // Enable CH1 output
TIM1->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE; // Enable TIM1 global outputs
TIM1->SMCR |= (0b010u << TIM_SMCR_TS_Pos) // TIM3 is the master
        | (0b110u << TIM_SMCR_SMS_Pos); // Slave mode: Trigger

// TIM2 Settings
TIM2->ARR = 8000 - 1; // 1 kHz PWM @ 8 MHz TIM clock frequency
TIM2->CCR1 = 4000 - 1; // 50% duty cycle
TIM2->CCMR1 |= (0b110u << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos); // PWM Mode 1
TIM2->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E; // Enable CH1 output
TIM2->SMCR |= (0b010u << TIM_SMCR_TS_Pos); // TIM3 is the master
// Slave mode will be configured later, otherwise TIM2 too starts with TIM1

// TIM3 Settings
TIM3->ARR = 800 - 1; // 100 us period @ 8 MHz TIM clock frequency
TIM3->CR2 |= (0b001u << TIM_CR2_MMS_Pos); // Master Mode: Enable
TIM3->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; // Start TIM3 -> This also triggers & starts TIM1
TIM3->CR2 &= ~TIM_CR2_MMS; // Reset master mode
TIM3->CR2 |= (0b010u << TIM_CR2_MMS_Pos); // New Master Mode: Update (for TIM2)
TIM2->SMCR |= (0b110u << TIM_SMCR_SMS_Pos); // Slave mode: Trigger
```

Comment: The board STM32F302R8 does not have TIM3. Only timer 1, 2, 6, 15, 16, 17.

Comment: Timers of the board in question are explained here: https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00094349-stm32f302xb-c-d-e-and-stm32f302x6-8-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf Maybe you could tell which timers I can use in my case so I can try your method.

Comment: I tried to use TIM2 master and T1M1 and TIM15 as slave timers by looking at ITR for them but it didnt work.

Comment: @ty_1917 , the config you mentioned should work. What was your observation? If you configured slave timers using CubeMX, maybe the generated init code activated slave mode for bot slaves at the beginning, which causes both slaves to start at the same time. For the second slave, slave mode needs to be activated after master timer starts.

Comment: @ty_1917 , I'm not familiar with HAL libraries, but if you update your question to include the solution I mentioned, I can have a look and check the init sequence. And please remove the unrelated functions (unused handlers etc.) & /* USER CODE ... */ lines from your code when pasting it here. They cause too much noise and make code hard to read.